# apache 2.4 + php 5.4.7 cannot load php5apache2_4.dll

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, php

I am trying to make Apache (httpd-2.4.3-win32) to work with PHP 5.4.7 (VC9 x86 Thread Safe) 
on Windows 7.

Apaches default page is working and proudly says: "It works". 
PHP CLI is working and reports version 5.4.7

I downloaded php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip from apachelounge and extracted the dll for 5.4.7 it to ~/php/ext/

When I add

```
LoadModule php5_module "...../php/ext/php5apache2_4.dll" 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

the apache service refuses to start and Event Viewer says:

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 526 of C:/.../bin/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/.../bin/php/ext/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I used php thread safe version, both php and apache 32 bit.

What am I missing ? Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Give us more information about the system being used. This sounds like your trying to load a 32-bit dll into a 64-bit Apache process.  I base that statement on the error your getting.

Comment: I am positive ( I just rechecked ) that both are 32 bit versions.

Comment: I have the same issue and i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

The correct version of php5apache2_4.dll should be in the root of your PHP folder.  The latest thread-safe Windows 32-bit PHP binaries are Version 5.4.15, at http://windows.php.net/.  You should not need to download php5apache2_4.dll from anywhere else, and I certainly wouldn't advise doing so.

So http.conf should contain:

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/php/ext/php5apache2_4.dll
```

The latest Apache 2.4 Win32 binaries from Apache Lounge are in httpd-2.4.4-win32.zip.

Finally, try changing your line: "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php" to:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

By the way, if you want to run Apache 2.4 64-bit, you need to [use the 64-bit PHP available only from Anindya's Blog](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-12-and-5-3-22-x64-64-bit-for-windows/).

Without seeing the rest of your configuration, I can't think of anything else, other than a path set wrong somewhere, but there are various useful tutorials around (see, for instance: [Apache, PHP, and MySQL Setup on Windows](http://www.ross.ws/content/apache-php-and-mysql-setup-windows)).

I've just done a complete webserver installation tonight, and the complete Apache/PHP installation using the above sources took about an hour (including mistakes!).

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.6 needs Microsoft VC++ re-distributable 2012. Once this is installed, it should work fine.

Comment: FWIW ... trying to install/run a 3rd party app bundled with Apache_2.4/PHP_5.6.40 and getting the same `can't load php5apache2_4.dll` message as OP; this (install VC++ re-dist 2012) got me up and running!

Answer (score -1):

You will need install Visual C++ RedistributableforVisualStudio 2012 from site Microsoft